# Node inspector offline?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I am writing a nodejs application and I am relying heavily on the node inspector (specific the [Node Inspector Manager (NiM)](https://github.com/june07/NiM).  I would like to work on my application and use the inspector in Chrome, even without a live wifi or internet connection.  Its a given of course that the rest of my app can indeed be worked on without a live internet connection.

When I disconnect my internet on my mac, and try to load the inspector, I get chrome's "no internet" page from within the devtools:

[image]

However I can see that my application is running just fine when I view it in the terminal.

My script to run my app with the inspector on is `node --inspect -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./src/server.ts` (some extras in there for typescript and babel).  When I run it, I see `Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/4478a0d7-e8a3-4315-8d2e-069a4e1e6389`.  I then navigate to `https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@a6b12dfad6663f13a7e16e9a42a6a4975374096b/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/4478a0d7-e8a3-4315-8d2e-069a4e1e6389` (not manually, I've set up NiM to open this open automatically).

Is this a known bug?  Is there some setting I need to adjust?  How can I utilize the node-inspector in Chrome with applications running locally, even if wifi is not present?

Comment: how are you accessing the site? only localhost/127.0.0.1 etc will work if you not connected to the net 192.168.1.* etc wont work

Comment: Good question.  I added some details about how I am launching my app with the inspector, and how I am accessing it in chrome

Comment: `https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com` is not local

Comment: Wow, didn't even notice that.  I am using the [NiM chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en)...why would it be using some remote site?  Shouldn't this be running completely locally on my machine?  And if its not, how can I tell it to do so?

Comment: idk, never used it. To open normal inspector use `chrome://inspect/#devices` it will then detect the websocket and then you can go straight into it

Comment: Yup, the problem is NiM, I have no idea why its routing through some third party url.  Works as expected when using nodejs devtools directly through chrome.  NiM is definitely a great tool with great features, but for offline mode, I'll have to ditch it.  If you want to write an answer with some of these details, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer.  Thank you!